# seconds value in timestamp in filename gettin rounded off sometimes

Tags: c++, timestamp, filenames

For one task I have to create files with the timestamp attached in filename for uniqueness. There is another program which reads these files. The condition for the other program to pick these files is that the filename should contain 14 digits of timestamp (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS) which I am getting through SYSTEMTIME. The issue I am facing is that sometimes the seconds field comes as e.g '10', in the filename it is getting rounded off and only '1' is getting displayed as the seconds field in timestamp. The other program doesn't pick this file because the timestamp now contains only 13 digits. How can I solve this issue by any method other than checking the length of timestamp and adding a '0' in the end.

Thanks
Mahboob

Comment: How are you generating your timestamp? Make sure to convert it to string before system evaluate it to something and roundoff the last 0

Answer (score 0):

Attaching some example codes is better to describe.

I used codes as below, haven't met problem you are facing.

```
  int64 timestamp = time(NULL);
  char data[kFileNameLength + 1]; 
  tm time_struct;
  strftime(data, sizeof(data), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime_r(&timestamp, &time_struct));
  return std::string(data);
```

Comment: I am trying to add milliseconds as well to the timestamp using commands           SYSTEMTIME timer; 
WORD millis = timer.wMilliseconds;
and it returns 3 digits. But if the last digit is 0 it rounds it off and returns 2 digits only

Comment: All I used are the standard C built-in functions. You had a try ?

Comment: Yes. I had a try. Maybe I was not able to completely articulate my question. Actually my issue arises when I combine both my question and my earlier comment. I am using strftime() function with similar parameters, but when I use WORD and add milliseconds I face this issue

Comment: This link kind of helped me in understanding what I need to do. [link] (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17576/SystemTime-to-VariantTime-with-Milliseconds)